# Reading image to byte array and changing it

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am trying to work with MemoryStream in C#.
So, I do converting Image to byte array and byte array to Image.
Like this

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("1.jpg");
var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, true);
var image = Image.FromStream(ms);
pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

It works fine (displaying image in picture box). But when i try to change byte array

```
bytes[0] = 254
```

It throws exception invalid parameter.
So, how I can change byte array or write bytes to stream? ms.WriteByte not works. Thanks

Comment: please show more your process of "changing the byte array". That is the code that is failing, that is what we need to see.

Answer (score 0):

JPEG (JPG) file is compressed representation of an image. It has complex structure, it is not byte matrix. Modification of first byte in it will most likely render it invalid. You better apply your modifications to `image`. And then save image as JPEG.